# function with arguments in python

Tags: python

I'm learning how to program with python.
I wrote this little program which counts the number of a character in a string.
Actually my function do not take parameters and wait for the user to do so.
I would like my function to take 2 parameters. One for the string and the other one for character to search.
Here is my script:

```
def count():
#word = 'banana'
 count = 0
 word = raw_input ('Enter a string:')
 letter = raw_input ('Enter a character:')
 for letter in word:
  if letter == 'a':
   count = count + 1
 print count

print count()
```

I would like to run my function like this:

```
>> count('banana', 'a')
3
```

Comment: Just define with: `def count(word, letter):` and remove the `raw_input` lines.

Comment: OK, then; what's the question? Maybe take a look at [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Voted to close: this is much too trivial to be of any use for future readers, I think. I'm surprised that whatever source the OP has learned what they apparently already know didn't cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count(word, letter):
  count = 0
  for l in word:
    if l == letter:
      count = count + 1
  return count

word = raw_input('Enter a string:')
letter = raw_input('Enter a character:')
print count(word, letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def count(word, searched):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == searched:
            count = count + 1
    return count


word = raw_input('Enter a string:')
letter = raw_input('Enter a character:')
print count(word, letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method count of a string.

```
def count(word, character):
    count = word.count(character)
    return count

word = raw_input ('Enter a string:')
letter = raw_input ('Enter a character:')

print count(word, letter)
```